# Laravel 5 can't show video

Tags: html, video

trying to show video in Blade,but get error :

```
<p>Video preview:</p>
<video width="640" height="360" controls preload="none">
    <source src="/var/www/dev.test/public/videos/test.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/var/www/dev.test/public/videos/test.mp4"  type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Error:

```
GET http://dev.test/var/www/dev.test/public/videos/test.mp4
```

Permission of videos folder iz 0777...

When play out of Laravel,no problem...

tnx

Comment: The path is bad. Try /videos/test.mp4 
src="/videos/test.mp4"

Comment: Thas solved problem!